# Angular.js with Sinatra

Tags: javascript, sinatra, angularjs

I would like to use Angular.js in my Sinatra applications. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any useful tips on this. I did find some Rails examples, however I have always found Rails and Padrino rather difficult to deal with, compared to the minimalistic philosophy of Sinatra.

I watched a number of videos (found by Googling angular.js), but am still finding it difficult to apply to Sinatra.

The most comprehensive tutorial I found so far was [one](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/08/use-angularjs-to-power-your-web-application.html) from yearofmoo.com.

But still I am lost trying to apply this to Sinatra, and hacking my way out of this appears not to be an option as a simple error anywhere might set me off the right path anyway. I am lost and I admit it!!

Kindly any help based on your experience of trying to do something similar would be much appreciated, if shared. All I need at this point is to path my JSON from a Sinatra app to angular.js powered pages.

Thanks.

Comment: In reality, AngularJS basically replaces the need to do any server-side templating. Your webserver becomes a source of REST/AJAX data and files, and that's about it. So you'd develop an angular application, then tie sinatra into it, and probably not the other way around.

Comment: I was getting that from all the material i found; but what about routes-based security?? and anyway how can I do this glue between the server and angular.js? 

and if this is the case, would you recommend using an api library such as grape instead of sinatra?

Comment: Routes-based security can be handled by Angular and enforced by your server. Since Angular is doing the routing client side, you would protect the *data* that your app is showing at the server side (since the data is what you want to secure). I would definitely recommend an API host over the standard web UI server framework.

Comment: Many Thanks for your response, and all of this sounds promising and efficient-again even if using sinatra is unnecessary, for experimental purposes it shouldn't be a problem to illustrate with 1 example that i failed to find anything similar online!! 

I want to be able to fetch data from sinatra and render it using angular.js; inconcept this should be possible, am I right??

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. I'm not a Sinatra expert, but if you were to set up some route in sinatra that returned JSON with content-type: application/json, you could use `$http.get('/MySinatra/Route').success(function(data) { /*do whatever*/ });`

Comment: this is where i am lost, according to the MVC nature of angular.js where should this code go and what complements it in other parts of the angular.js?? and how and where can i pass my json to angular.js from sinatra?

Comment: I've added an answer that illustrates the basic idea. It can obviously get a LOT more involved, but I hope that it helps you go in the right direction. I'm the wrong guy to ask about hosting Ruby web APIs in Sinatra though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I stated in the comments above, the application structure would no longer rely on the server for templating the UI or generation of markup. Your server would essentially be a data and file host.

Okay.. presuming you have some route in Sinatra set up to return the following json (with content-type: application/json):

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Foo" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Bar" }
]
```

You would then use something like this in Angular to load that data (basically):

app.js

```
//create your application module.
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//add a controller to it
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

   //a scope function to load the data.
   $scope.loadData = function () {
      $http.get('/Your/Sinatra/Route').success(function(data) {
         $scope.items = data;
      });
   };

});
```

Then in your markup you'd do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="loadData()">Load Data From Server</button>
    <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in items">ID: {{item.id}}, Name: {{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: unfourtantly code doesn't work for me, i am suspecting it is missing somthing in the app.js??? 

<!-- language: lang-js -->
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {
 ['$scope', 'loadData'];
);

Comment: Thank you very much Blesh, it works now, this is a good start for me. with this little hands-on knowledge.. I am putting my effort in reading the documentation now

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/overview

Cheers,,,

Answer (score 3):

I found [this Sinatra tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-single-page-web-apps-with-sinatra-part-1/) was helpful even though it uses Knockout.js not Angular. It helps you build a Sinatra application that returns JSON, and it was quite straightforward to take the concepts and code from the [Angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) to connect to this simple backend.

Comment: Thanks heyotwell, I already checked it out while comparing angular against knockout.js & backbone.js. It is always good to know that some piece of code works for someone so if it doesnt work with you; you can take your efforts to where the problem really is. for instance I also faced a problem with CORS. which I resolved. 


ruby -rrack -e "include Rack;Handler::Thin.run Builder.new{run Directory.new''}"



- http://enable-cors.org/ 
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/